# VirtualBox Guest Additions: Debian 11

Tags: debian

Has anyone had success installing latest guest additions on Debian 11?

I downloaded the latest VirtualBox and Extensions pack, mounted the Guest Additions CDROM, ran the script and 'sudo lsmod|grep vbox' reports 'vboxsf and vboxguest' in use.  Unfortunately, I can't mount my shared folders and auto screen resizing doesn't work.

Thanks